# adding a confirmation box in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make code which will continuously show the confirmation box whenever a mouse movement occurs. I tried many but none are working for me.

In my code, I need a confirmation box just having OK and Cancel.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0  
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

$("#onediv").mousemove(function(evt){
alert("hai");
});

});


</script>
<style type="text/css">
div{

background-color:orange;
border:5px solid black;
height:400px;
margin:10px
}
</style>
</head>
 <div id="onediv">
sdfas
</div>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For starters, place your `<div>` inside the `<body>` element

Comment: I don't think you should be using confirm (or alert) on mousemove. The user will move the mouse, the confirm (or alert) will pop up, and they'll move the mouse to click the button - thus interrupting wherever they were going to move it to. So they move it again and the confirm (or alert) comes up again. Annoying. Also, what do you mean by "continuously show the confirmation"? Once the confirm (or alert) appears your JavaScript code will be blocked waiting for the user to click a button so really "continuously" doesn't come into it.

Comment: @nnnnnn I don't think he literally means to confirm each single mouse move, and this is just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: yes.. it was for demonstration of jquery to have some attention from others.nothing more important..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do this

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {    
//   do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the native Javascript `confirm` function:

```
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to do this?"))
{
    alert("Confirmed!");
}
else
{
    alert("Denied, foo!");
}
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for..in mozilla there is an option to prevent further script alerts. So that users can easly prevent it.. anyway for internet explorer its  working..thanks..